# How to display particular workbook of Excel file on TV and no matter what i do on the computer the TV displays the workbook

Tags: multiple-monitors, tv, microsoft-excel-2003

I have a computer and a TV.I want to display particular workbook of excel file on the TV ( monitor 2 ) and when I work on my computer monitor ( Monitor 1 ) nothing happens on Monitor 2.I need that because I have linked cells from Workbook 1 and Workbook 2. And lets say I work on Workbook 1, so when I change the linked cells in Workbook 1 they change automatically on Workbook 2 that I need to be displayed on the TV.So no matter what I do on my computer the TV always displays Workbook 2.

I'm using Excel 2003 and Windows XP (with NVidia graphics)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to superuser!
You need to run two sessions of excel to do this.
First open workbook 1 and place it in computer monitor.
Next,
Go to Start(menu)->Microsoft Excel. This will open another session of excel. Now move this to the TV. On the excel shown on TV, go to "File-Open" and open the work book 2 on this.
Now you will be able to see one file on computer monitor and one file on TV.
Comment if you have further queries

Comment: Yea but when we open two sessions of excel i cannot link cells between them.I can link cells only in one session of excel

Comment: Would arranging workbooks ("arrange windows horizontally or vertically) on your TV be of any help? Here we can maintain one session and hence the link would be maintained.